# Meaning of にまでなる

Tags: grammar, culture, particle-まで

> まあっ、なんて欲ばりな女だろうね。あんたみたいな犬がねぇ、くわえてた肉を池におっことしたって話が、童話**にまでなってる**よ。
>   Come now. What a greedy girl. The story of a dog like you which dropped a piece of meat it was holding in its mouth into the pond **is becoming a fairytale**.

I'm sure I've got the end of this translation wrong. I don't understand にまでなってる in this sentence.

Also, the whole sentence is bizarre. I guess this is a reference to a Japanese folk-tale. I know it's off-topic but a quick summary of what this sentence is referring to would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

にまで in this sentence is used in an emphasis of the dimension. 童話にまでなってる is translated as "The story even become a fairytale." and "The story do become a fairytale."

For example,　彼は大臣にまでなった.(He even became a minister. He did become a minister.)

And I guess this story isn't a reference to a Japanese folk-tale but Aesop's Fables like "The dog and its reflection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_and_Its_Reflection

Answer (score 1):

> くわえてた肉を池におっことしたって話

That refers to "the dog and its reflection", one of Aesop's Fables.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_and_Its_Reflection

> 童話にまでなってるよ

It is
童話になってるよ (it has become a fairy tale.) + まで (it means "even" in this case.)

I think your confusion is due to the meaning of "なる." Why, this is not "童話になった" but "童話になっている?" (It is also fine to use "なった" here, but in that case, I feel you need to have some emphasis on the exact timing "it became a story.")

"なる" is basically translated as "become." But, this word is often a little bit different from "become" in my opinion.
It also means "achieve", "actualize", "be evaluated to be", etc.

In this case, "become" is fine, but maybe the next sentence would give you some ideas.

> That story (has achieved / is evaluated) to be a fairy tale.

So,

> The story is known even as a fairy tale.

would be an idiomatic translation.